# Docker как подключиться к контейнеру?

Tags: windows, docker

У меня установлена windows 10 и докер на ней. В докере создал контейнеры `MariaDB` и `adminer`.

Запустил так `docker run --link mysqlserver:db -p 8080:8080 adminer`

Пытаюсь зайти через браузер `127.0.0.1:8080` не получается

Пытаюсь `192.168.99.100:8080` не получается

Пытаюсь `172.17.0.3:8080` не получается

Так как я могу подключиться к `adminer`?

Comment: Запустите контейнеры через sudo.

Comment: В смысле? На windows sudo?

Comment: Всегда описываю все сервисы в `docker-compose.yml` и не испытываю проблем ни с чем, всегда структурированы сервисы и все предельно понятно. Начните с этого. И да, все сервисы доступны по адресу: `127.0.0.1` без каких-либо проблем, конфигурация у нас с вами одинаковая, а значит что-то неправильно делаете только вы.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию docker назначает для виртуальной машины, на которой разворачиваются контейнеры, ip адрес 10.0.75.1. Исходя из того, что вы запускаете контейнер с SQL Server, то вам необходимо открыть SSMS (или иную IDE) и подключиться к инстансу по адресу 10.0.75.1,8080 (для SSMS двоеточие заменяется на запятую!)

Comment: Мне нужно открыть это в браузере.